# SQL Query needed to get information from TWO separate tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I am trying to create a query that will list all books by the same author. Most of the list has only one book by one author, but I want the author that has multiple books listed in db to display those book for that author.

I have two tables:

- **Book** - `AuthorID, BkTitle`, etc
- **Author** - `AuthorID, AuthFName, AuthLName`

I want the result to be sorted by `AuthLName` and the report to consist of any books in db that have same `authorid`.

Example result wanted:

```
 AUTHORID BKTITLE           AUTHFNAME     AUTHLNAME
--------- ----------------- ------------  -----------
    504   KNIGHT FREEDOM     Chris        Feehan
    504   KNIGHT SHOWDOWN    Chris        Feehan
```

Currently, I have the following code:

```
select AUTHORID, BKTITLE
from BOOK 
where AUTHORID in
    (select AUTHORID from
       (select AUTHORID, 
               count(*) as BOOK_COUNT
        from BOOK
        group by AUTHORid
        order by AUTHORid )
     where BOOK_COUNT >= 2);
```

which gives:

```
  AUTHORID BKTITLE
---------- --------------------
       504 KNIGHT FREEDOM
       504 KNIGHT SHOWDOWN
```

I need to find a way to get the information from the Author Table and add it in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT b.AUTHORID, b.BKTITLE, a.AUTHFNAME, a.AUTHLNAME
FROM BOOK b
  INNER JOIN AUTHOR a
    ON b.AUTHORID = a.AUTHORID
AND b.AUTHORID IN
(
  SELECT AUTHORID
  FROM BOOK
  GROUP BY AUTHORID
  HAVING COUNT(AUTHORID) > 1
)
ORDER BY a.AUTHLNAME, a.AUTHFNAME
```

Comment: This is also listing all books in db. I only want those books that have the AuthorID listed on more than 1 book to show up.

Comment: @ReneCanter - Answer updated to include only books that have authors or more than one book.

Answer (score 1):

How about this - updated to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) first to figure out which authors have more than one book in the database table `BOOK`, and then listing only those authors and their books:

```
;WITH AuthorsWithMoreThanOneBook AS
(
    SELECT AUTHORID, BOOK_COUNT = COUNT(*)
    FROM BOOK
    GROUP BY AUTHORID
    HAVING BOOK_COUNT > 1)
)
SELECT
    b.AUTHORID, b.BKTITLE, a.AuthFName, a.AuthLName
FROM
    BOOK b
INNER JOIN
    AUTHOR a ON b.AuthorID = a.AuthorID
INNER JOIN 
    AuthorsWithMoreThanOneBook A2 ON a.AuthorID = A2.AuthorID
ORDER BY
    a.AuthLName, a.AuthFName
```

**Update:** OK, you're using Oracle .... not sure (haven't used it in ages) - but can't you just extend your original query something like this:

```
select bk.AUTHORID, bk.BKTITLE, a.AUTHORFNAME, a.AUTHORLNAME
from BOOK AS bk
INNER JOIN AUTHOR AS a ON a.AUTHORID = bk.AUTHORID
where bk.AUTHORID in
    (select AUTHORID from
       (select AUTHORID, 
               count(*) as BOOK_COUNT
        from BOOK
        group by AUTHORid
        order by AUTHORid )
     where BOOK_COUNT >= 2);
```

Not sure if/how Oracle supports those table aliases (`BOOK AS bk`) - but I'm pretty sure it does support it some way or another....

Comment: I am thinking perhaps the OP means to constrain the query to authors that have more than one book? Not sure though.

Comment: That lists all columns but it also lists all books. I only want to list those books by the same author.
An example:

        AUTHORID BKTITLE              AUTHFNAME            AUTHLNAME
        512 DARK SHADOW          CAMERON              DEAN
        587 KNIGHT PRINCE        DARYLL               DEANLOP
        504 KNIGHT SHOWDOWN      CHRISTINE            FEEHAN
        504 KNIGHT FREEDOM       CHRISTINE            FEEHAN
The only books should be listed is the Authorid of 504 because there is more than one in the db

Comment: Sorry, cant get it to format correctly. But author id 504  has two books in database. so i want those two only listed because all other authors only have one book in db

Comment: @ReneCanter: updated my answer to figure out the authors with more than one book using a CTE (works in many RDBMS - you unfortunately didn't mention which one you're using)

Comment: sorry, im using Oracle. With the above, I get error:
                                *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Thanks for your help!!  Not sure why it is still erroring. Oded did list something that works though. I really appreciate all your help!!! Your guys are the best :-)

Comment: I believe you have to put the expression following an ON clause in parentheses - as in `ON (b.AuthorID = a.AuthorID)`. In any case, it's worth a try.  Also - I don't believe there should be a semicolon before the 'WITH' in the CTE.  Dang computers!  So blasted picky..!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only one access to each table:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT AuthorID, BkTitle, AuthFName, AuthLName
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AuthorID)
         AS c
  FROM BOOK
  JOIN AUTHOR USING (AuthorID)
)
WHERE c > 1;
```